# How to convert a pixel array to a dds

Tags: c#, xna, sharpdx

I have an array of pixels (WriteableBitmap.Pixels), and I need to save it as a DDS image.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this? I have looked at the Humus image converter, aswell as DevIL, but I just have no idea...

I feel like there should be SOMETHING built in to do this.

I am using c#/SharpDX/possibly XNA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharpDX.Toolkit.Image.Save is actually providing DDS saving. Moving pixels from WriteableBimap.Pixels to Image.Pixels shouldn't be an issue.

The only thing that Image.Save is not providing is format conversion. You cannot save a compressed format for example (BCm format from DXGI)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the pixel data stored in a buffer you could just grab the DDS file format reference and write out the data yourself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943991.aspx

Comment: Ya, I was looking at that DDS guide. I have the pixel information (ie. the color of each pixel), but I am not sure how to actually save them. Is it just a text file, with no delimination? Or do I just put commas where the commas are in the doc?

Comment: A DDS file is a binary file containing a DWORD format identifier, a DDS_HEADER structure, and a DDS_PIXELFORMAT structure that defines how the pixel data is stored in the the file. There are many versions of a DDS, so check out that MSDN page for the specifics on each versions format.